# Moving oldest folder based on name (YYYYMMDD)

Tags: c#

I have a directory of around 30-40 folders that contain various backup files for a CRM system.

I have developed a script that downloads the files from a remote server, and places them in folders with `YYYYMMDD`, however due to space restrictions I now need to move the oldest folder from the directory. As the IT team at the company keep moving the folders between servers I cannot use the folder creation date!

What is the easiest option? I have looked at: [deleting the oldest folder by identifying from the folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261045/deleting-the-oldest-folder-by-identifying-from-the-folder-name) and attempted to order the items then perform a move.

My other option was to take all of the folder names in the root directory, parse into a list of type time and date, select the lowest (oldest) option, then perform the file move?

Comment: "I have looked at... and attempted" - but? What did not work for you? If you don't make clear how your question differs from that one, it will likely be regarded as duplicate.

Comment: I also do not get your problem. If the folder names are in `YYYYMMDD` format a simple "alphabetic order" should do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
    bool MoveOldestFolder(string initialFolderName, string destinationFolder)
    {
        // gets all top folders in your chosen location
        var directories = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(initialFolderName,"*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        // stores the oldest folder and it's date at the end of algorithm
        DateTime outDate;
        DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        string resultFolder = string.Empty;

        // just a temp variable
        string tmp;

        // using LINQ
        directories.ToList().ForEach(p =>
        {
            tmp = new System.IO.FileInfo(p).Name; // get the name of the current folder
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(tmp,
                                       "yyyyMMdd",  // this is case sensitive!
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                       out outDate)) // try using folder name as date that "should" be in yyyyMMdd format - if the conversion is successful and date is older than current outDate, then store folder name and date, else nothing
            {
                if (outDate.Date < oldestDate.Date)
                {
                    oldestDate = outDate;
                    resultFolder = p;
                }
            }
        });


        // if we actually found a folder that is formatted in yyyyMMdd format
        if (!oldestDate.Equals(DateTime.MaxValue))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Move(resultFolder, destinationFolder);

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // handle the excaption
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // we didnt find anything
            return false;
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var initialFolderName = @"C:\initial";
    var destinationFolder = @"c:\dest";

    if (MoveOldestFolder(initialFolderName, destinationFolder))
    {
        // move was successful                
    }
    else
    {
        // something went wrong
    }
}
```

Other option would be to simply do what `chrfin` said but I wouldn't presume on everything being "dandy" in the folder structure. There is always a possibility that the folder name is not in YYYYMMDD format and that would probably cause some problems I imagine.
Anyway, the code could look something like this:

```
    var directories = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(initialFolderName,"*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    directories.ToList<string>().Sort();
    var lastDir = directories.First();
```